# Dynamic query is not giving desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating dynamic query which is updating column if it exists in the table. When update query is running it giving error. Following is the procedure

```
Create Procedure spr_UpdateColumnWithTotalPrice
@id int
as
begin

if not exists
(
    Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = 'Product'
    and
    COLUMN_NAME = 'ProductSellingPrice'
)
Begin
    Declare @SellingPrice varchar(max)


    Set @SellingPrice = 'Alter table Product add ProductSellingPrice int'
    Exec(@SellingPrice)

    Print 'Table altered'
End
Else
Begin
        Set @SellingPrice = 'Update Product set ProductSellingPrice = ((UnitPrice * [GSTRATE%]/100) + UnitPrice ) where  ProductID  = @id'
        Exec(@SellingPrice)
        Print 'Table updated'
End
```

end

I am getting following result :-

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Update Product set ProductSellingPrice = ((UnitPrice * [GSTRATE%]/100) + UnitPrice ) where  ProductID  = @id' to data type int.

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: The exact query you posted would not produce the error you say you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Set @SellingPrice = 'Update Product set ProductSellingPrice = ((UnitPrice * [GSTRATE%]/100) + UnitPrice ) where  ProductID  = '+ CAST(@id as varchar(13))
```

You can't use `+` to concatenate an int to a string, since SQL Server will try to implicitly convert the string to an int.
This is why you need to explicitly convert the int to a string.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @RamandeepSingh . . . You should accept this answer if it fixes your problem.